# What is an efficient way to map a file to array of structures?

Tags: c, arrays, file, memory

I have a file in my system with 1024 rows,

**student_db.txt**

```
    Name   Subject-1  Subject-2  Subject-3
    -----  ---------  ---------  ---------
    Alex     98         90         80
    Bob      87         95         73
    Mark     90         83         92
    ....     ..         ..         ..
    ....     ..         ..         ..
```

I have an array structures in my C code,

```
typedef struct
{
  char name[10];
  int  sub1;
  int  sub2;
  int  sub3;
} student_db;

student_db  stud_db[1024];
```

What is the efficient way to read this file and mapping to this array of structures ?

If the number entries is less then we can go for normal `fgets` in a `while` with `strtok` but here number of entries is **1024**.

So please suggest some efficient way to do this task.

Comment: SO is no coding service. Show what you have done and where your **specific** problem is. If you have trouble understanding your assignment, ask your tutor.

Comment: By seeing how data is organized in file , you probably cant escape loop.

Comment: And keeping 'Bob' in `char name[10];` lets Bob have a nickname as well.

Comment: I am asking about methods like `mmap ()`

Comment: `mmap` does not parse your file. It is useless hee, as you only have to read it once from a stream anyway.

Answer (score 5):

1. Check the size of the file, I think, it is max. 100 KByte. This is literally nothing, even a poorly written PHP script can read it in some millisec. There's no slow method to load such small quantity of data.
2. I assume, loading this file is only the first step, the real task will be to process this list (search, filter etc.). Instead of optimizing the loading speed, you should focus on the processing speed.
3. Premature optimization is evil. Make a working unoptimized code, see if you're satisfied with the result and speed. Probably you never should optimize it.

Comment: There is no use in loading the whole file to memory first, as that can be easily parsed in a single pass.

Comment: True premature optimization is very very wrong. But if it's the case, consider saving information to file in binary format. Drawback is, that you will not be able to read this file by opening it in a file editor, but processing will be faster. You will be forced to use programs to operate efficiently on this file.

Comment: @Olaf, I don't see where he's suggesting you should.  In C, my first pass would probably be a `getline` loop.  Maybe `fgets` if portability was a concern.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland: "2. I assume, loading this file is only the first step" sounds like he actually **is**

Comment: If raw speed actually is a concern, I'd: (1) read the entire file at once, (2) iterate a `char` pointer over it, (3) filling in a pointer to `student_db`, (4) not minding niceties such as `strcpy` (I'd use `memcpy`) and `atoi` (for small numbers I'd roll my own, minimally and inlined). Can't check now but it'd run in a fraction of a second, apart from the initial reading. That said: only the very worst programmer would be able to make this task go *slow*.

Comment: @Jongware - I think a more interesting challenge would be to make it as slow as possible without using any worse-than O(N) approach :).  Maybe pipe, fork, and exec another program to give you each byte?  Make a shell script to do your `atoi`?

Comment: @DawidPi - Can you please explain the saving file in binary format - and faster processing method, even it is not readable on editor it is no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store data in a binary way. The way file is written now is character way. So everything is represented as a character (numbers, strings and other things).

If you store things binary, then it means you store numbers, strings and other stuff the way they are, so when you write integer to a file you write a number, when you open this in a text editor later, then you will see character, which corresponding number in eg. ASCII is the one you have written to a file.

You use standard functions to store things in a binary way:

```
fopen("test.bin","wb");
```

`w` stands for write and `b` stands for binary format. And function to write is:

```
fwrite(&someInt, sizeof(someInt), 1, &someFile);
```

where someInt is variable you want to write (function takes pointer),
sizeof(someInt) is sizeof element int,
1 stands for number of elements if first argument is an array, and someFile is a  file, where you want to store your data.

---

This way size of the file can be reduced, so loading of the file also will be faster. It's also simplier to process sata in file